# ArcGIS online: Publishing map service, error code 400

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I update a webmap on ArcGIS Online on a daily basis from an mxd in ArcGIS desktop, from where I update 8 of the 10 layers. I have used the "overwrite an existing service" with success until recently. Now I get the following message:

> Packaging succeeded, but publishing failed. ERROR: code:400. Unable to
>   delete item. This Service item has a related Service item, Bad syntax
>   in request. Please consult the GP results window for enhanced error
>   description or contact your administrator for the server logs.

None of the layers have relates, or can these be hidden? What has happened since I started getting this error notification is that I have moved/copied these 10 layers and the mxd to a onedrive location, could this affect the update?

If i build up a new .mxd from scratch I get a notice saying that the caching size is 31GB and will be very slow to upload. I did not get this message earlier, even with the same layers. I have never touched the caching settings.

Is there perhaps an easier way of updating a webmap daily? Is there a difference between adding (altered) feature layers and overwriting the map service?

I am using ArcGIS desktop 10.3.1

Comment: What kind of update is it? You add/remove features to existing layers?

Comment: A bit of both: I change four point layers that hold only 1 point each, so I both remove and add. I also lengthen four lines, adding approximately 20 meters to 5-6 kilometer lines per day = adding features.

Comment: I am not well-versed in python, do you have the opportunity to share an example? Or will this not work in desktop at all? Thanks in advance.